# C++ overriding functions in classes set specifically for partial template specialization

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing a point cloud class with several features (using Eigen as the linear algebra library). I wanted to implement some specific function for only 3 dimensional point clouds. Therefore I implemented the general class hierarchy in the following way in which I partially specialize one of the template arguments for the point cloud:

```
template <typename T, unsigned int DIM>
class PointCloudBase {
   public:
    using Vector = Eigen::Matrix<T, DIM, 1>;
    using Hyperplane = Eigen::Hyperplane<T, DIM>;
    using MatrixDIM = Eigen::Matrix<T, DIM, DIM>;
    using AlignedBox = Eigen::AlignedBox<T, DIM>;

    bool convexHullIntersects(const AlignedBox& box) const {
       // generic implementation for this function
    }

    // more stuff here

};


template<typename T, unsigned int DIM>
class PointCloud : public PointCloudBase<T, DIM> {

};


template<typename T>
class PointCloud<T, 3U> : public PointCloudBase<T, 3U> {
  public:

    using typename PointCloudBase<T, 3U>::AlignedBox;
    using typename PointCloudBase<T, 3U>::Vector;
    bool convexHullIntersects(const AlignedBox& box) const override {
      // implementation specific to DIM = 3U
    }
};
```

However when I try to instantiate the class as `PointCloud<double, 3U> pc;`, I get the following error that complains that convexHullIntersection is not overriding anything:

`error: ‘bool PointCloud<T, 3>::convexHullIntersects(const typename PointCloudBase<T, 3>::AlignedBox&) const [with T = double; typename PointCloudBase<T, 3>::AlignedBox = Eigen::AlignedBox<double, 3>]’ marked ‘override’, but does not override`

What can be the problem here?

Thanks!

Comment: `convexHullIntersects` needs to be declared `virtual` in `PointCloudBase`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved the problem.